# how to split a string with special characters in oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g

I want to split the below string based on certain string. How can we do this?

```
abc\\10.2.4\\string with spaces\\1.2.3-another-string\\def\\string_with_underscores
```

split by 'def'

Comment: Take a look at oracle regular expression functions.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use `regexp_replace` as in the following query :*

```
with tab(str) as
(
 select 'abc\\10.2.4\\string with spaces\\1.2.3-another-string\\def\\string_with_underscores' 
   from dual 
)
select regexp_replace(str,'def.*','') str1,
       regexp_replace(str,'.*def','') str2
  from tab;

    STR1                                                   STR2
-------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------
abc\\10.2.4\\string with spaces\\1.2.3-another-string\\    \\string_with_underscores
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do any good?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc\\10.2.4\\string with spaces\\1.2.3-another-string\\def\\string_with_underscores' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(replace(col, 'def', '#'), '[^#)]+', 1, level) res
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, 'def') + 1;

RES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc\\10.2.4\\string with spaces\\1.2.3-another-string\\
\\string_with_underscores

SQL>
```

- lines 1 and 2 represent your data
- lines 3 - 5 are used to split that column into rows

  - line 3: REPLACE replaces 'def' with '#' which becomes a new *delimiter*
  - line 5: you'll have as many rows as there are 'def' delimiters in a string + 1 (i.e. if there are 4 'def' delimiters, you'll have 5 rows as a result)

This option doesn't require you to know *in advance* how many substrings you'll get as a result, it is *dynamic*.